# Insert based on inner join oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table A with three columns a b c. I want to insert values in to columns a and b based on the join of column c with another table B

I am using the following query

```
MERGE INTO A
USING
(SELECT * FROM B) **B**
ON (B.c=A.c)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
INSERT(a,b) VALUES(local_varialble,'STRING');
```

I am getting the following error

```
PL/SQL : ORA-00905 : MISSING KEYWORD
```

Please help !! This query always seems to be tricky

EDIT : I found out that using != in the ON condition and following it up with WHEN NOT MATCHED compiles perfectly.. but I don't know whether it yields the correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You want to insert some data into table `A` when there is connection between rows in tables `A` and `B`, but you do not use any values from columns of the `B` column.

Merge won't work like the way you wrote it, because you **have to** have either an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement in the `WHEN MATCHED THEN` clause, you can not have an `INSERT` there. On the other hand, in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` clasue, you can have **only** `INSERT`.

More about `MERGE` here: [Oracle Documentation - MERGE Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

If you change from `=` to `!=`, it won't work, because then you will be doing an `INSERT` in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` part of `MERGE`, and what you want is to `INSERT` when there is a match between the records.

So, to sum up - what are you trying to achieve? I think that you shouldn't use `MERGE` in that particular situation, instead use a simple `INSERT` with well defined condition which rows should be inserted and from where.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to define first a "merge_update_clause" (see [merge documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm))

like this:

```
MERGE INTO A
USING (SELECT * FROM B) b
   ON (B.c = A.c)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ....
     DELETE WHERE ...
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...
```

Comment: Sorry but Why do you use Merge statement?

Answer (score 0):

untested but, change your sql to this

```
MERGE INTO A
USING
(SELECT * FROM B) B
ON (B.c=A.c)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
INSERT(a,b) VALUES(lorcal_varialble,'STRING');
```

I added

```
(SELECT * FROM B) B
```

to your sql

When you are referencing the using select, you should alias it like I did

Comment: I used the alias in my query, just forgot to mention it here. Still, the query is not working